# PHP - access 2 different databases from one class

Tags: php, mysql, database, ado

Please help me set the required database! Thank you!

```
<?php
require_once("adodb5/adodb.inc.php");

$web = NewAdoConnection("mysqlt");
$server     = "*";
$user       = "*";
$password   = "*";
$database   = "web";
$web->Connect($server, $user, $password, $database);

$modul = NewAdoConnection("mysqlt");
$server     = "*";
$user       = "*";
$password   = "*";
$database   = "modul";
$modul->Connect($server, $user, $password, $database);

$rs = $web->execute("SELECT DATABASE()");
echo $rs->fields[0];    // EXPECTED: "web", ACTUAL: "modul"
?>
```

Comment: well just call using $DBM->execute instead of $DB->execute in your last query. But I'm not sure what the question exactly is??

Comment: If I create $DBM after that I have to specify the database otherwise I got an error: command denied to user 'web'@'localhost' for table xy

Comment: The question is: how can I achive to set default database ($DB -> "web", $DBM->"modul") when I get the instance from Main class.

Comment: I modified your question to get rid of the extra confusion. The code I posted produces the same problem you were seeing. See my answer below for a possible solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, but I think you're looking for the `__construct` function.

**EDIT**:

Scratch that, I understand your question better now. It looks like you need to use [ADOdb_Active_Record](http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-active-record.htm). Specifically, look at part 17. [This page](http://kaixersoft.wordpress.com/2011/08/04/dealing-with-multiple-db-connection-with-adodb-orm/) may also be helpful.

Comment: I'm not looking for __construct. I try to eplain better. But thanks anyway!

Comment: The answer is much more easier than I thought before, I dont even need to use ADOdb. :)

mysql_connect($host,$user,$password);
$db1 = "web"; $db2 = "modul";
mysql_select_db($db1);
$rs_from_db1 = mysql_query("...");
mysql_select_db($db2);
$rs_from_db2 = mysql_query("...");

Comment: Well, yeah...there's that. I guess I assumed that you had a more specific reason for using ADOdb, like portability. I suppose I should have asked that.

Comment: Maybe in the future I'll use what you recommend.

Comment: Also, make sure you protect your database from SQL injections. For any data that comes from the user, always use `mysql_real_escape_string($value)` or, as a better example: `mysql_query(sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($username)));`